# Не помещается краткое описание привелегии "Просмотр голосов, карточка участника, которую можно расширить"

Tags: дефект, локализация

Краткое описание следующей привелегии не умещается:

[image: Следующая привелегия]

В оригинале звучит как "see votes, expandable usercard". Можно перевести как "Просмотр голосов, расширяемая карточка пользователя", хотя и это описание может не уместиться.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вот интересно, с одной стороны это действительно дубликат, с другой стороны если нажать кнопку "это решило мою проблему" - это будет не правдой)

Comment: Надо наверное предложение написать именно по исправлению данного описания))